# Meu modal não abre

Tags: javascript

O modal esta funcionando normalmente porem não abre dentro dessa função, sou bem leigo em javascript

```
        $(function($) {
        $('#frmLogin').submit(function() {

            $('div.mensagem-erro').html('');    

            $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(resposta) {

                if (!resposta)
                    window.location.href = '3.php';
                else
                {
                    $('div.mensagem-erro').html(resposta)
                    $('#recebeusalario').modal();
                }

            });

            return false;

        });
    });
```

Comment: Olá! Aparece algum erro no console do navegador?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (2.php:78)
    at Object.options.success (jquery.form.js:149)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: A função alert funciona normal, e a função modal também esta funcionando normal mas ai uso assim :   var estavaemp = function(){
    $("#estavaemp").modal()
   }

Comment: A função modal não funciona nesse lugar, apenas a função alert!

Comment: poderia explicar um pouco mais o que está fazendo? também ajudaria colocar o código do HTML que está sendo usado